# My page is not redirecting at my Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, web

Hello I'm working with PHP.At this moment i have just inserted data in database by php code.Just name and email + submit.
But i want when i will click on submit then it will back to homepage.As far i know i did true code.
Please check ->

```
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ajx');
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  if(empty($name) || empty($email)){

      echo "<h3 style ='color:red; text-align:center;'>Filed must not be empty</h3>";

  }else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name,email) VALUES('$name','$email')";
    $conn-> query($sql);
    echo "Data insert Okay";
    header("location : index.php"); 

  }
```

The front end shows this message:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500

localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.4

Comment: Please read about prepared statements. Just. Please.

Comment: `echo "Data insert Okay";` remove this line from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirection is not working, because you have already sent headers. Remove the echo before the header() and it should work.
If you want to send any headers there **MUST NOT** be any output before you do so. Not even a single space.

Also, as I said in my comment, please dont use mysqli the way you do, look into prepared statements.

Comment: "Still not working" is not very clear. What does happen, what errors do you get? If you dont get any errors, try turning them on via `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Hello Manuel Mannhardt echo was not any problem.Problem was with the single space.You mentioned in your comment.
Thank you .
Now working.

Comment: Well, if there would not have been a space, the echo would have been the problem :P 
Please accept my answer if I helped you :)

Comment: i already voted but showing this line- Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Voting is not accepting. You should be able to accept an answer to your own question. Thanks

Comment: But how i can accept your answer please can you tell me?
Because i have created account here just 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Under the voting option there is a check sign click on that to accept the asnwer.